# System.Speech does not recognize speech while debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, speech-recognition, speech-synthesis

I was going to make a forms application in C# that recognize a voice and then the user could say some simple commands like "hi" and the computer would respond with "hi there, can I help you with someting". I am 100% sure that my mic works but when I debugg the program it seems like it does not recognize any commands or audio from my microphone. I am using Visual Studio Community 2015. I was wondering, is there anything i've missed or done wrong? The computer loads up the form and talks to me but it doesn't recognize my voice. I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using System.Speech.Recognition;

namespace VoiceHost
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SpeechSynthesizer Host = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        Choices services = new Choices();

        public Form1()
        {


            SpeechRecognitionEngine UserRecog = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();

            services.Add(new string[] {"hi"});

            Grammar gr = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(services));
            Say("hello, my name is voice host, how can I help");

            try
            {
                UserRecog.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
                UserRecog.LoadGrammar(gr);
                UserRecog.SpeechRecognized += UserRecog_SpeechRecognized;
                UserRecog.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
                UserRecog.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
            }
            catch { return; }
        }
        public void Say(string responseMessage)
        {
            Host.Speak(responseMessage);
        }

        private void UserRecog_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            string userOrder = e.Result.Text;

            if (userOrder == "hi")
            {
                Say("hi there, can I help you with someting");
            }
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

}

Comment: The first thing you're doing wrong is `catch { return; }`; that hides errors and when you're programming you need to know about errors.

Comment: What do you mean "what is a good way"? Just don't catch exceptions and then do nothing about them. At the least log them.

Comment: catch the exception and look in in the .Message and innerException.Message.. or log it, or display.. just don`t ignore it

Comment: for example catch (Exception e) { MsgBox.Show(e.ToString()); }

Answer (score -3):

catch { Exception ex }
that way you'll see if anything breaks in your code.